# custom jquery not being read using gulp in laravel

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, gulp, bower

I am trying to add some custom jquery to a form and for some reason it's not working! It's showing that gulp is reading it so I know gulp isn't the issue. I have jquery downloaded using bower and there doesn't seem to be an error in the console.

here is my jquery file:

```
var defaultValue = 50; 

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');

      if($(this).val()) {
         $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
    } else {
       $('#display-amount').text('--');
       $("#btn2").removeClass('active');
       $("#btn3").removeClass('active');
    }
});

     $( ".selectvalue" ).click(function() {
        $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
     });

    $(".buttons .btn").click(function(){
        $(".buttons .btn").removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
      $('#donation-amount').css("background-color","") 
    });
$("#donation-amount").click(function() {

         if ($(this).hasClass('inpt-first')) {

             $(this).css("background-color", "#c97e06");
             $("#default").removeClass('active');
             $("#btn2").removeClass('active');
             $("#btn3").removeClass('active');
             $('.donation-amount').val("");
            $('#display-amount').text('--');
         } 

        else{
            $("#default").addClass('active');   

        }

    });
$('#donation-amount').blur(function() {
  $(this).attr('style', '');
  if($(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == 'Custom') {
    $('#default').addClass('active');
    $('#display-amount').text(50);
  }
});

    $('#display-amount').text($('#default').val());

});
```

and here is my form:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="form-container">
    <div class="donate-heading text-xs-center">
        <h1>Support our Students!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="form-content">
        <form action="" method="post" id="payment-form"></form>
            <span class="payment-errors"></span>
            <div class="content-inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend class="text-xs-center">How much would you like to donate</legend>
                            <div class="choose-pricing">
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <div class="buttons">
                                        <button type="button" id="default" class="btn btn-default active selectvalue hover-color" role="button" value="50">50</button>
                                        <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" role="button" value="100">100</button>
                                        <button type="button" id="btn3" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" role="button" value="150">150</button>
                                        <input type="Custom" name="donation-amount" class="inpt-first" id="donation-amount" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="Custom">
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="donation-amount-value" id="donation-amount-value">
                                </div>
                                <div class="money-donate">
                                    <div class="display-amount" id="display-amount"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <legend class="text-xs-center">Enter your card details</legend>
                <div class="credit-card-num">
                    <input type="text" name="cardNumber" id="creditCardNumber" style=" background-color: #f4f4f4;" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="Enter yor 16 digit card number" data-stripe="number">
                </div>
                <div class="date-wrapper">
    <div class="month">
      <span class="full">Month &amp; Year of Expiry:</span>
      <select name="month" id="expMonth" class="selectBox chzn-done" data-stripe="exp-month">
        <option data-stripe="cvc">Select Month</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
      <div id="expMonth_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1">
        </a>
      </div>
      <select name="year" id="expYear" class="selectBox chzn-done" data-stripe="exp-year">
        <option value="">Select Year</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cvn">
    <span>Card Verification Number</span>
    <br>
     <!--  <span class="full">

      </span> -->
      <input type="password" name="cardVeriNum" id="cardVeriNum">
    </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset class="personal-detail">
    <legend class="text-xs-center">Personal Details</legend>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="notes" class="form-control" id="addnote" placeholder="Additional Notes"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group button">
      <div class="text-xs-center">
      <button id="donate-btn" value="Donate" class="btn btn-default">Donate</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

here is my gulp file:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    // Copy Styles
    mix.copy('bower_components/bootstrap/scss/', 'resources/assets/sass/libraries/bootstrap/')
       .copy('bower_components/css-hamburgers/_sass/hamburgers', 'resources/assets/sass/libraries/hamburgers/')

    // Copy Scripts
    .copy('bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'resources/assets/js/libraries/jquery.js')
    .copy('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js', 'resources/assets/js/libraries/bootstrap.js')


    // Compile App Assets
    .sass('app.scss','public/css/app.css')

    .scripts([
    'libraries/jquery.js',
    'libraries/bootstrap.js',
    'app/**/*.js'
    ], 'public/js/app.js', 'resources/assets/js')

    // Create version
    .version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

Comment: how are you loading the js within the browser EG: <script src="???"> etc will need to see that etc, do a simple view source and see where the file if at all is being called, unless its not been loaded as mentioned

Comment: I'm using bower and gulp and gulp is reading my files just fine.

Comment: gulps fine but is the HTML page loading it in, whats the rest of your html ouptu, do a view source as i have a feeling its not  loading your actual outputted js file

Comment: Its so weird. It seems to be loading my js just fine. The view source shows it's there.

Comment: how are you loading it as i see your using version(), so are you doing like `<script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script>` also to test the js above works add a console.log('hello you') jsut after the document ready code and when viewing the page check the browser console to see if you get that text 'hello you' if not then its defo not loading it, or running it. If so post the whole view source file result as well